# Not able to pass function to child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I don't understand what is happening, the syntax seems to be right, but I'm receiving this error:

TypeError: chooseMessage is not a function

```
// PARENT COMPONENT

import React, { useState } from 'react'


export default function LayoutMain(props) {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState("Hello World");

    const chooseMessage = (message) => {
        setMessage(message);
    };


    return (
        
        <div>
            <LayoutMenu>
                 <Navigator chooseMessage={chooseMessage} />
            </LayoutMenu>
        </div>
    )
}



//CHILDREN COMPONENT

export default function Navigator({chooseMessage}) {
   
    let msg = 'Goodbye';
    
    return (
  
            <div className='navigator-header' onClick={() => chooseMessage(msg)}>
                 test
            </div>
    )
}
```

I've read articles about lifting state up and also watched some videos and followed the instructions carefully over and over again but had no success.

#NEW UDPATE

I just realized that my code is definitively correct, it must be something related to the compiler or something.

Comment: I copied your code and worked for me https://codesandbox.io/embed/angry-mopsa-zwuuwn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: The child component should not be editing parents component state, use the function to pass the string so the parent can setState with the argument

Comment: @Woohaik that's what I'm trying to do, but the function is not being recognized.

Comment: @Woohaik I found out that the problem is related to something in my project. The code is right :/ I have no idea what it might be

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, maybe you have a typo somewhere else, or maybe you are using Navigator somewhere else without passing the function to it.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps others ... I was hit with a similar error message (~Not able to pass function to child component in React) but I felt I was "doing everything correctly".

What I found was that, in my parent class, I created two instances of the child class and in one instance of the child class I did not need and therefore did NOT pass as a parameter the necessary function to the child component.   However this was the source of my issue - once I corrected this, the error went away.

(Read: you can ofc fix this by either passing the function from the parent into all child components or by making sure you are doing some checks in your child component so that the passed function is not strictly necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass setMessage from the parent down to the child, then you can use the message state in the parent, and pass message down to the child if you want to use it in the child as well.

```
export default function LayoutMain (props) {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('Hello World');

    return (
        <div>
            <LayoutMenu>
                <Navigator setMessage={setMessage} />
            </LayoutMenu>
            <p>{ message }</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default function Navigator({ setMessage }) {
    const chooseMessage = (message) => {
        setMessage(message);
    };
    
    return (
        <div className='navigator-header' onClick={() => chooseMessage('Goodbye')}>
            test
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Still not working, I realized that my code is right and yours too. The problem is something messed up in my project. I'll keep looking for a solution.

Comment: Your `onClick` should be `onClick={() => chooseMessage('Goodbye')}` currently it will invoke it immediately

Comment: @RubenSmn still got the same error, setMessage is not a function

`export default function Navigator({setMessage}) {

    const handleMessage = (message) => {
        setMessage(message)
    }

    return (
        <div className='navigator'>
            <div className='card'>

                <div className='navigator-header' onClick={() => handleMessage('Goodbye')}>
`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the code is working fine. However, you can control all the logic from one component that can be a parent controller and expose methods as props to interact with them it will be easier to manage the state there.

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-smoke-57v1bk?file=/src/App.js